# know if a boolean changed its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

when I load up the page the console log prints **true** but when i click the button nothing happens. I think that the event listener might help but i'm not quite good at javascript please help

```
<button class="shuffle">shuffle</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var player = $("#audioPlayer")[0];
var length = $("#queue li").length;
var shuffle = true;

$(".shuffle").on('click', function() {
    if (shuffle === true) {
        shuffle = false;
    }else{
        shuffle = true;
    }
});
if (shuffle === true) {
    console.log('true');
}
if (shuffle === false) {
    console.log('false');
}
```

Comment: move `});` to end?

Comment: `$(".shuffle"){}` what is this?, syntax error I think

Comment: no because i want it to print true when the page loads and also work when i click on the button

Comment: @Desperado it was a mistake

Comment: @ShubhSheth ok, there is nothing wrong with your code, after on click how did you check if shuffle is true or false? Is this the if conditions that followed the event? It it is, move the conditions inside the vent same as bansi said. Codes in your code are not executed sequentially

Comment: @Desperado actually i'm making a audio player so the default option doesn't shuffle anything but if the user clicks on shuffle i want it to shuffle the playlist

Comment: Add `console.log(shuffle)` to the click handler function if you want it to happen when the user clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a function that performs what you want to do. Then you can call it when the page loads, and also when the user clicks.

```
function do_player_stuff(p) {
    if (shuffle) {
        console.log("Shuffling");
    } else {
        console.log("Not shuffling");
    }
}

$(".shuffle").on("click", function() {
    do_player_stuff(player);
    shuffle = !shuffle;
});

do_player_stuff(player);
```

Comment: yes but i want it to be unshuffled at first and do its task and when the user clicks on shuffle it performs another task (its like the music player in your phone)

Comment: Whatever you want it to do, put that in the callback function.

Comment: i get you but i want it to perform the task of **true** by default and then the user can toggle between true and false

Comment: What's the problem? When the user clicks the button, you check the value of the variable, and perform whatever action is appropriate depending on the value, and also toggle it.

Answer (score 0):

You code seems to be working. However you can simplify it like below.

```
var shuffle = true;
$(".shuffle").on('click', function() {
    shuffle = !shuffle;
    //Do whatever code you want to run when boolean changes
});
```

Comment: is there any way that i can just toggle the boolean and add an event listener

Comment: @ShubhSheth What event do you want to listen for beside the click? There's no event when a variable changes its value.

Comment: What kind of event listener ?

Comment: how will you detect if a boolean's value was changed

Comment: @ShubhSheth Your script is changing it itself, it doesn't need to detect anything.

Comment: Your boolean will not change automatically. Your code will change it. So when your code changes it you can run whatever function you want.

Comment: its a music player so it plays the songs normally by default so that means my boolean is set **true** by default but when user changes it i want it to detect and run another code

Comment: whatever code you want to run, you can run it inside the `'click'` event.

Comment: @Arif but i don't want to put the same code in two places

Comment: @ShubhSheth Write a named function that does what you want, and call it from the click handler. Then you only have to write it once.